# LongTextField cannot be search on admin search bar

Tags: shopware, shopware6

After I changed to `StringField` to `LongTextField`, the search bar cannot search on that field anymore.

How I can make the field `LongTextField` searchable?

old code

```php
public function defineFields(): FieldCollection
{
   return new FieldCollection([
      ... other fields
      new StringField('old_url', 'oldUrl'),
   ]);
}
```

current

```php
public function defineFields(): FieldCollection
{
   return new FieldCollection([
      ... other fields
      new LongTextField('old_url', 'oldUrl'),
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find any references in the code that would make a difference between these two types regarding the search in the administration. Try adding the `SearchRanking` flag to control the weight of the field within the search.

```php
(new LongTextField('old_url', 'oldUrl'))->addFlags(new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::HIGH_SEARCH_RANKING))
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is add search flag to that field like this:

```php
public function defineFields(): FieldCollection
{
   return new FieldCollection([
      ... other fields
      new LongTextField('old_url', 'oldUrl')->addFlags(new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::HIGH_SEARCH_RANKING))
   ]);
}
```